# How to detect a rectangle block from an image and change it to white color?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

How can I remove a black color rectangle from an image like this below,

[image]

I want to detect that huge black color rectangle box and change it to white color? Its my next pre-processing stage.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: please review [ask]. you're expected to *attempt to solve your own question*, not just ask it and free source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert to gray
- Threshold to binary and invert
- Get the largest external contour
- Get the bounding box for that contour
- Fill that region of the input with white
- Save the result

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('black_rectangle.png')
ht, wd = img.shape[:2]
print(img.shape)

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,128,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# invert
thresh = 255 - thresh
    
# get largest external contour
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# get bounding box of largest contour
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(big_contour)

# make that region white in the input image
result = img.copy()
result[y:y+h, x:x+w] = (255,255,255)
    
# show thresh and result    
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# save resulting image
cv2.imwrite('black_rectangle_2white.png',result)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Size of image should not matter. The code finds the largest contour and then gets its bounding box dimensions to make white.